# On Wordpress DB, WP_Posts and WP_Postmeta relations issue

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I am trying to run an SQK query that will pull a Post content (from WP_Posts) and it's attached image (from WP_Postmeta).
For some reason I cannot correlate the data from those two sources.
When I am using WP_posts.ID = WP_postmeta.post_id on joining queries I cannot get both content and the attached images URL.
Sorry if my question is not clear enough, it's 2AM here :)
Thanks in advance, Pavel

PS.
Let's say my content is in WP_posts.ID = 4. For some reason, the corresponding attached image is on WP_postmeta.post_id = 5 and so forth. Can I do some math magic to connect the two since they are always x+1 from each other?

Answer (score 1):

The attached images for a post will be in the `wp_posts` table with a `post_type` of "attachment", and their `post_parent` ID set to the `ID` of that post. Effectively, each attachment is stored as a post in its own right, and it's the `post_parent` that says which post the attachment is attached to.

So, to retrieve all the attachment metadata rows (there will probably be more than one) for all attachments to the post with ID 1898, say, try something like:

```
SELECT
    wp_postmeta.*
FROM 
    wp_posts the_post 
        INNER JOIN wp_posts the_attachments ON the_post.id = the_attachments.post_parent
        INNER JOIN wp_postmeta ON the_attachments.id = wp_postmeta.post_id
WHERE
    the_attachments.post_type = 'attachment' AND
    the_post.id = 1898
```